# Set ng2 component template with variable?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

Is it possible to set the template url of an angular2 component with an input variable? The solution below doesn't work because `step` isn't defined until below the component details. But I am curious if something like this could work?

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'demo',
    templateUrl: step;
})
export class demoComponent {
    @Input()
    step: string;
}
```

and then call it like:

```
<demo [step]="path/to/template"></demo>
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of doing things like this?

Comment: No, It won't work. It is used at the compile time to make bundles and then `step` won't be defined.

Comment: @Harangue Well I am writing a tutorial app and I have a load of parsed git diff files for each step. I want to be able to reference the `<codestep [step]="2.1">` tag and for the correct static html (rendered code snippet) to be displayed. However, there is some logic I want all snippets to perform.

Comment: @ritz078 Is there anything like for example just having an empty template with 1 data binding and then passing in all the static html to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[innerHTML]` to bind dynamic HTML. Additionally, `Input()` won't be set until the component is rendered.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'demo',
    templateUrl: `
        <div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
    `;
})
export class demoComponent {
    @Input() step: string;

    private content: string = '';

    ngOnInit () {
        if (this.step === "foo") {
            this.content = "bar";
        }
    }
}
```

You may have to explicitly set the markup as safe depending on how you're inserting it, just so you're aware.

Comment: Just to mention it because there are often wrong expectations. Angular doesn't process HTML added this way except some sanitization. It just passes it to the browser. No components or directives are instantiated no matter if selectors would match, no bindings (`[prop]="xxx"`) are evaluated and no event handlers (`(event)="handler($event)"`) are added.

Comment: In connection to this, how would I "read" a file served on my domain and set `this.contents` to equal it's contents? Sounds like a real NOOB question, but it it an HTTP call, or would I just use a web address?